# Build series of sqlite3 queries and save it as meta sql?

Tags: sql, import, sqlite

I know you can build sequence series in sqlite 3 and save it as file, so the next time you don't have to rewrite some queries, but is it possible to save meta queries as well - specially regarding .import? I am anyway importing from same file, but it seems you can not build a sequenced query with sqlite manager, because it would save original source data in file.

I am looking for a solution I would not need to write this for an example:

```
sqlite3 Data.db
create table Product (name varchar, price float);
.separator ",";
.import data.txt Product;
create table Product2 (name varchar, price float);
insert into Product2 (name, price)
select name, price from Product group by name;
.etc
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [view](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html):

```
CREATE VIEW Product2 AS SELECT name, price FROM Product GROUP BY name;
```